# Conditionally inserting elements into vector

Tags: r

I am trying to adjust some vectors so that they are all the same length, in order to place them into a data frame. The vectors were generated from using `coef` calls on various `lm` models. The problem comes from the fact that not every variable occurs in every `lm` call, so some of the vectors are shorter than others, however the variables missing from any specific regression can be random, for example:

```
>regression1
(Intercept)    var1        var2        var3         var4 
-0.08324358  5.52612036 -0.30234773  1.68640397 -0.45661553

>regression2
(Intercept)    var1        var2        var3 
   2.894916    5.029081   -1.838681   -4.570308 

>regression3
(Intercept)    var1        var2        var4
16.35817775  3.35612118  0.07659903 -1.50003495 

>regression4
(Intercept)    var1        var2     
16.35817775  3.35612118  0.07659903
```

so I need to make the last three vectors look like:

```
>regression2
(Intercept)    var1        var2        var3    var4
2.894916     5.029081   -1.838681   -4.570308   0
>regression3
(Intercept)    var1        var2        var3    var4
16.35817775  3.35612118  0.07659903     0    -1.50003495 
>regression4
(Intercept)    var1        var2        var3    var4
16.35817775  3.35612118  0.07659903     0       0
```

I am using this test:

```
vars <- c("(Intercept)","var1","var2","var3","var4")
test<- vars %in% names(regression3)
```

Which gives me a logical vector indicating which variables are missing like so:

```
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE
```

I am trying to fill in the FALSEs with 0's by using this call

```
regression3 <- ifelse(test,regression3,0)
```

which seems to work if the missing values are located sequentially at the end (so if var3 and var4 are both missing, it will work), but in the case above where there are TRUE values after it, this will cause the last element to equal the first element, rather than the fifth. Is there something wrong with my ifelse statement, or is there another efficient way to add 0's to my vectors conditionally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it:

```
setNames(replace(numeric(length(vars)), 
                 vars %in% names(regression3), regression3), vars)

(Intercept)        var1        var2        var3        var4 
16.35817775  3.35612118  0.07659903  0.00000000 -1.50003495
```

This replaces zeroes in a numeric vector with the values for the present variables.

Comment: thanks, this is exactly what I needed! Any idea why my ifelse statement was behaving oddly for future reference?

Comment: @user3203398 If the `yes` and `no` arguments of `ifelse` are shorter than the `test` argument, their values are recycled. In your example, `test` is of length 5, while `regression3` is of length 4. At position 5, the first value of `regression3` is used again.

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to place your 'regression vectors' into a data frame, then you may try this: put the vectors in a list, convert them to data frames, bind data frames together using `rbind.fill` from `plyr` package ("`rbinds` a list of data frames filling missing columns with `NA`"), and replace `NA` with zero.

```
library(plyr)
mods <- list(regression1, regression2, regression3, ...)
mods2 <- lapply(ll, function(x) as.data.frame(t(x)))

mods3 <- do.call(rbind.fill, mods2)

mods3[is.na(mods3)] <- 0
```